# null returned when fetching data from firebase using expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase in my expo app
so this is the component where I implement this code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAVf",
    authDomain: "d07f5.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://d07f5.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "d07f5",
    storageBucket: "d07f5.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "66392528"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

const api = 
    firebase.database().ref('/Barbers').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('testing')
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    });

  export default {
    getBarbersShops,
  }
```

when I run the app on my android device and seeing the remote debugging from the console of browser I find the " testing " word that I write in console but for this console:

```
console.log(snapshot.val())
```

I just got null for it and can't understand why?

and this is image for collection in firebase:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting null because your code is accessing Firebase Realtime Database, but the picture of your data is showing it stored in Cloud Firestore.  These are not the same products - they share neither the same data nor the same APIs.

Answer (score 2):

doug stevensons answer is totally right! To get the document from firestore in react native, you can use the following code:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

myFunction(){
    firebase.firestore().collection('Barbers').doc('9R4t...').get().then(doc => {
       if(doc.exists){
          console.log(doc.data().name);  // testing
       }
    }
}
```

or async:

```
async myFunctionAsync(){
    const doc = await firebase.firestore().collection('Barbers').doc('9R4t...').get();

    if(doc.exists){
       console.log(doc.data().name);  // testing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for examples it's so useful @Sean Stayn